# JNI returning Java object, is it OK to return local reference, or must it be global?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, return-type

Say in a JNI method I want to return a Java String (or any other Java object.) Can the returned object be a local reference created within that method, or should return value be converted to a global reference?

Trivial example:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_some_package_SomeObj_getStringTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    return env->NewString("Test", 4); // OK to return local reference?
}
```

Or should it rather be:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_some_package_SomeObj_getStringTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    jstring str = env->NewString("Test", 4);
    return env->NewGlobalRef(str); // Must return a global reference?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#global_and_local_references)

> ### Global and Local References
>
> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two categories: *local* and *global references*. Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.
>
> Objects are passed to native methods as local references. **All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references**. The JNI allows the programmer to create global references from local references. JNI functions that expect Java objects accept both global and local references. **A native method may return a local or global reference to the VM as its result.**

So, your first example is perfectly fine and legal:

```cpp
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_some_package_SomeObj_getStringTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    return env->NewString("Test", 4); // OK to return local reference?
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, somehow to me it was difficult to find. I was worried about "Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed after the native method returns" statement - it seems to suggest that all, including the objects returned from a JNI method, would be freed.

Comment: @gregko all local references created inside a native method are subject to garbage collection when the method exits. That includes the return value, if it is not assigned to a variable on the Java side to prevent garbage collection. Think of smart pointers in C++. Locally declared smart pointers destroy the objects they hold when they go out of scope, unless you extend their lifetime (assign to another smart pointer, etc), even on a `return`. It is similar in JNI.

Answer (score 0):

The former, I've done it. Works as expected.